# Why setting shouldRasterize to YES does not improve my performance for my collection view cell?

Tags: ios, calayer, uicollectionviewcell

I want to check if shoudlRasterize will improve my performance.
I've created my custom subclass for UICollectionViewCell and added this method:

```
- (void)configureCell 
 {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 50.f;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
 }
```

I called this method in my VC where is my collection view:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    
    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath        
    {
       static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
       CRTCustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CRTCustomCollectionViewCell *)   
       [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier 
       forIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell configureCell]
       return cell;
    }
```

But when I tried to add self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES to my configureCell  method I still have bad performance, maybe +3-5 FPS max improvement.

Comment: I suspect your issue probably has more to do with the loading images in your cells. Check for synchronous loading of images or long running functions.

Comment: nothing related to image loading. 
I simply want to understand why using shouldRasterize doesn't improve my performance.

Comment: if performance is bad, you should load instruments and review performance there to narrow down the problem. As for shouldRasterize, What makes you believe it should be faster?  As per the docs... "When the value of this property is NO, the layer is composited directly into the destination whenever possible. The layer may still be rasterized prior to compositing if certain features of the compositing model (such as the inclusion of filters) require it."

Comment: Using cornerRadius hoses performance I find.